# Hibernate Validation - how to get annotation type?

Tags: hibernate, validation

Here is my TO class to validate:

```
public class Person {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = ID.REGEX)
    private String id;

    public Person(String name, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And validation method:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Person person = new Person(null, "notCorrextIdRegex");
validator.validate(person).stream().forEach(constraintViolation -> {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to easily obtain annotation type which has failed during validation? I need this to create Exceptions with various error codes depending on constraintViolation like:

**@NotNull** -> **new Exception("Object is null or empty.")**

Is it good approach to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **group sequences** (see [the docs on chapter 2.3.1](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) for info and examples) to group your constraints (with the `groups` attribute) as you prefer.

Comment: Put your comment as an answer and accept it, so I can delete mine if it's not useful.